# "PSQLException - cannot create enum of unspecified type" when using enum type in where clause

Tags: postgresql, enums, jdbi, cockroachdb

We are using JDBI in Kotlin with cockroachDB. I am seeing the below error when a field of type enum is queried in where clause

> "errorMessage":"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot create enum of unspecified type [statement:"\n      SELECT \n      p_id,\n      c_id,\n      o_id,\n      p_earned,\n      p_redeemed,\n      event_source,\n      created_at,\n      updated_at\n      FROM my_table_1\n      WHERE o_id = :oId\n      AND event_source = :eventSource\n     ", arguments:{positional:{0:fff1526c-8ff8-47d7-a303-04f388970f2b,1:PROMO_APPLIED}, named:{oId:fff1526c-8ff8-47d7-a303-04f388970f2b,eventSource:PROMO_APPLIED}

This 'event_source' field in crdb table has an enum type constraint. And in code, we are just passing it as an enum.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_1 (
    id           UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    p_id         UUID NOT NULL,
    c_id        INT8 NOT NULL,
    o_id           UUID NOT NULL,
    p_earned      INT8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    p_redeemed    INT8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    event_source       event_source_type NOT NULL,
    created_at         TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT now():::TIMESTAMPTZ,
    updated_at         TIMESTAMPTZ NULL DEFAULT now():::TIMESTAMPTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY(c_id, o_id, event_source),
    INDEX(id),
    INDEX(p_id),
    INDEX(o_id),
    INDEX(c_id)
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS event_source_type AS ENUM (
  'P',
  'O',
  'OC',
  'PROMO_APPLIED'
);
```

```
@SqlQuery(
  """
    SELECT 
    p_id,
    c_id,
    o_id,
    p_earned,
    p_redeemed,
    event_source,
    created_at,
    updated_at
    FROM $TABLE_NAME
    WHERE o_id = :oId
    AND event_source = :eventSource
  """
)
fun getDetails(
  oId: String,
  eventSource: EventSourceType
): MPTransaction?
```

Any pointers on what might be going wrong? It works when -

1. If I hard code the event source value in the query like **AND event_source = 'PROMO_APPLIED'**
2. Or if I remove enum constraint from table column in crdb like **event_source       TEXT NOT NULL,**

Comment: When trying to read or write to that field you need to explicitly cast the value to `event_source_type`. Something like `'PROMO_APPLIED'::event_source_type`. Otherwise, Postgres will interpret it as a string or unknown type.

Comment: thanks @JSpratt.
It works when I typecasted to TEXT
`AND event_source::TEXT = :eventSource`